# Delays between byte writes on Raspberry Pi SPI bus

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B, and I'm using [SPIDev](http://tightdev.net/SpiDev_Doc.pdf) in python 2.7.

I'm writing a stream of bytes out of the SPI port and I see them and they are well formed, but there seems to be excessive (~4ms) delays between each byte. This appears to be causing trouble in device I'm writing to.

The delay is consistent across data rates, and happens whether I use spidev.writebytes() or spidev.xfer2() functions

Is this caused by other linux processes being serviced? Something in the SPIDev driver?

Has anyone else experience this, and/or know of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you execute your script with realtime priority via `nice`? `ionice` might also be relevant (not sure about this one).

Comment: @UliKöhler, thank you very much for the tip, but neither nice nor ionice seemed to make an difference.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help :-( But I'm pleased to see this issue has now been resolved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was a variety of contributing factors involved, essnetially I was processing and preparing data as I was writing it to the SPI port. When I rearranged the code so the data was all prepared ahead and the writes were done back-to-back, everything works as fast as I would expect.